# java agent Instrumented class file not reflected on PCF

Tags: java, javaagents, pcf

Need some help.

We have a custom java agent written using javaassist that instruments Logger file from logback for info method. The agent works as standalone program from command line, when used with -javaagent option, while running target app/class. It also works if a sample maven project is created in Eclipse and executed by Providing run configuration having -javaagent in run configuration.

Premain is called - transformer is called - instruments the class file - prints the log as updated using instrumentation.

**While pushing on PCF**:
The agent in packaged into spring-boot app binary, under MyApp.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\ This is very Simple Hello Program with one controller

**Issue is** 
    Premain is called - transformer is called - instruments the class file, **However does not print the log as updated using instrumentation**.

Do we need any specific configuration to get this instrumented file back to PCF?

Appreciate your inputs/queries.

Here is manifest.yml

applications:
- name: KedarTestApp
  memory: 2G
  disk_quota: 1G
  instances: 1
  path: target/Hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  env: 
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE : "dev"
    JAVA_OPTS: -javaagent:BOOT-INF/classes/Agent.jar

**Dev Env**:
JDK8, WIndows 10, cf version 6.26, cf cli

Comment: Above scenario works on local machine with below config from command line. Checking further towards how to push app to PCF  and how to pass this from manifest.mf

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.agent="\codebase\AgentProcess\Agent.jar"

Comment: Not found a way to do this yet, how to pass :: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.agent="\codebase\AgentProcess\Agent.jar"        from manifest.yml to push app to pcf     ......    ....any direction on this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case anyone needs it for refrence :)

If the instrumentation library is not on the class path - PCF wont show error/warning,but also wont instrument your classes.

The instrumentation libraries will be part of your binary, but are not loaded when PCF starts the app with org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.

You will need to provide the path to instrumentation libraries as part of -cp argument on your manifest's command: option.